# neo4j: Shortest path that includes specific relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the graph model below and am trying to write a Cypher query that finds the shortest path from a `Person` to a `Skill` that includes at least one instance of the relationship `HAS_SKILL` in the path.

In the model

- a `Person` is connected to another `Person` via the `IS_CONNECTED_TO` relationship
- a `Person` is connected to a `Skill` via `HAS_SKILL`
- a `Skill` is connected to another `Skill` via the `IS_RELATED_TO` relationship

[image]

I have come up with the following query, which works but unwraps all the relationships in the path to check that the `HAS_SKILL` relationship is one of the relationships.

```
match (person:Person {id: "48"}), (skill:Skill {id: '10667'}),
path = shortestPath((p)-[*..30]-(s))
WHERE ANY(r in relationships(path) where type(r) = 'HAS_SKILL')
return path;
```

Is there a more effecient way to do this?

I have played around with relationship pattern matching in `(p)-[*..30]-(s)` but I couldn't get it work in the same way that `ANY` in the where clause works?

This is using neo4j 4.1.0.

Comment: Is it possible for a path between a Person and a Skill NOT TO contain a relationship of type  `HAS_SKILL` ?? From your graph schema, it seems it's not?

Comment: that's correct here, but its only a subset of the full model. the full model does allow for alternate paths to `Skill`s not via `HAS_SKILL`

Answer (score 0):

If the center of universe is HAS_SKILL, I'd suggest looking into anchoring on that relationship, and then path find from the relationships start/end nodes.  Something like this

match (p:Person)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(s:Skill)

Then perhaps determine the shortest path from the specific person to those p, then take just the s skill's those shortest paths p point to and then shortest path find from those s to the specific skill.

I don't know if there is more we could suggest without knowing more about the actual model and challenge.

Answer (score -1):

you can use query like -

match (person:Person {id: "48"}) (skill:Skill {id: '10667'}),
path = shortestPath((person)-[:HAS_SKILL *]-(skill))
return path

This will traverse only through 'HAS_SKILL' edge.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).